# C++ get/set not getting value in switch case

Tags: c++, get, switch-statement, set, encapsulation

I have 2 classes `M` and `L` each with its own `.header` and `.cpp` files.

In class `L` there are get/set methods

```
    class L // this is in L.h file
{
      private:
    int A;
    float B;

    public:
        A();

        A(int,float);

        void setA(int A);
        int getA();

        void setB(int B); 
        int getNoOfEarthLikePlanets();

};

//L.cpp//

L::L() // default constructor
{
    A = 0;
    B = 0;  
}   

L::L(int aA,float bB) non-default constructor
{   
    A = aA;
    B = bB; 
}

void L::setA(int aA) // set A
{
    A = aA;
}

int L::getA() // get A
{
    return(A);
}

void L::setB(float bB) //set B
{

    B = bB;
}

float L::geB() // get B
{   
    return(B);
}
```

My class `M`:

```
#include "L.h"
void M::mainMenu()
{
    int choice = 0;
    cout<<" 1) enter your A and B:"endl;
    cout<<" 2) Display your An B :"endl;
    cin>>choice;

    yourChoice(choice);


}
void M::yourChoice(int choice)
{   
    const int size = 50;
     int cinA;
     int cinB;
    static int count = 0;
    L newL[size];

while(choice != 999)          
    {
        switch(choice)
        {            
            case 1:
            {                          
                 while(count<SIZE)
                 {                
                 cout<<"What is A : ";
                 cin>>cinA;
                 newL[count].setA(cinA);
                 cout<<"What is B: ";
                 cin>>cinB;
                 newL[count].setA(cinA);
                 ++count;  
                  //******i tried to cout my newL[count].getA(); it displays a blank too*********
                 mainMenu();      
                 cin>>choice;
                 break;    
                 };
        //Even if i bring newL
            } // end of case 1
        break;
       case 2:
        {
           for(int x = 0;x<size;x++)
                   {                          
           cout<<newL[x].getA()<<endl; //Prints a blank 
                   }       
        }//end of case 2
         }//end of switch
   }//end of while
```

I am using get/set to get the user input in case 1 and printing it out in case 2. However when after I input the details in case 1, I go to case 2, it displays nothing, not even a `0`, just blank. I have also tried putting static in front of my type variables because I thought it might be something to do between invocations.

And I also tried to `cout` the `getA()` in case 1 right after the I input the values, it displays blank too. What am I missing out? Pls request for more detail code if u feel other code I wrote might cause this to happen. This is only part of it.

In my `int main()` I just run `mainMenu();`

Comment: Whenever "yourChoice(choice);" is called, it is creating a new array of class L. Can you make newL[size] static and give a try? Also, in case1 block, make sure you are printing before "++count;"

Comment: or better: make it a class member of `M`!! you have an object there

Comment: You should read some more about functions and variable scope in your book. You're treating function calls like they were gotos.

Comment: The code you have posted is incomplete and it doesn't compile, it's not even close. You should start with something simpler. Try it with one class, then move up to something more complicated...

Comment: You are doing `setA` even for B value. Looks like a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(choice != 999)          
    {
        switch(choice)
        {            
            case 1:
            {                          
                 while(count<SIZE)
                 {                
                 cout<<"What is A : ";
                 cin>>cinA;
                 newL[count].setA(cinA);
                 cout<<"What is B: ";
                 cin>>cinB;
                 newL[count].setA(cinA);
                 ++count;  
                  //******i tried to cout my newL[count].getA(); it displays a blank too*********
                 YOUR TROUBLE MAKER>>>>>mainMenu();      
                 cin>>choice;
                 break;    
                 };
        //Even if i bring newL
            } // end of case 1
        break;
       case 2:
        {
           for(int x = 0;x<size;x++)
                   {                          
           cout<<newL[x].getA()<<endl; //Prints a blank 
                   }       
        }//end of case 2
         }//end of switch
   }//end of while
```

That trouble maker line creates a new instance of mainMenu therefore, another set of `newL` array which has no relations to your original `newL` instantiated in the original `mainMenu`. Since `mainMenu` itself calls another `yourChoice`.

## Recommendation

The addition of a Boolean mode is just to make sure you want a display of the main menu where the input is disabled. This way you can call `mainMenu(true);` if you want an input and `mainMenu(false);` if you only want a display

```
void M::mainMenu(boolean mode)
{
    cout<<" 1) enter your A and B:"endl;
    cout<<" 2) Display your An B :"endl;
    
    if(mode)
    {
        int choice = 0;
        cin >> choice;
        yourChoice(choice); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

forgivenprog33442
I think nothing is printing out because your code never actually goes to case 2 since you call `mainMenu()` right after your `++count` in yourChoice method, making recursion by accident. Just delete `mainMenu()` from your `choice` variable in yourChoice method and declare `choice` as a `private` variable in your class.

For example, you could do this for looping while choice is in the range you are working on

```
while(choice > 0 && choice < 3) 
{
    switch(choice)
    {
          case 1:
             while(count < SIZE)
            { 
             //loop until all number are set
             //then ask for choice
             //make sure you check if space in array 
             //or use a vector so it can resize automatically
             }
          case 2:
             //print your values
    }

}
```